# Replacing append html tag values with symbol or notations

Tags: php, dom, preg-replace

```
<span class="fwb">Harry and David</span>

<span class="fcg">Business Intelligence Developer/Analyst</span> 
<span class="fcg">Oct 1998 to present</span>
<span class="fcg">Medford, Oregon</span>

<span class="fsm fwn fcg">Creative writing</span>

In my html content 
<span class="fwb"> occured more than 4 times, 
<span class="fcg"> occured more than 10 times, 
<span class="fsm fwn fcg">Creative writing</span> occured  more than 5 times.
```

using php reg expression or DOMDocument() i need to replace the all the content to be appended with $ symbol.

For ex:

```
<span class="fwb">Harry and David</span> to be replaced by <span class="fwb">Harry and David$</span>

<span class="fcg">Business Intelligence Developer/Analyst</span> to be replaced by       <span class="fcg">Business Intelligence Developer/Analyst$</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand from your code samples (?) but I believe you're looking to append a `$` sign to the end of each of the `<span>` tags. Using [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to do this:

```
$str = '
<span class="fwb">Harry and David</span>
<span class="fcg">Business Intelligence Developer/Analyst</span>
';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
  $span->nodeValue = $span->nodeValue . '$';
  echo $dom->saveHTML($span) . "\n";
}
```

You could, as you said, also use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like so:

```
$str = '
<span class="fwb">Harry and David</span>
<span class="fcg">Business Intelligence Developer/Analyst</span>
';

$p = '{(<span[^>]*>)([^<]+)(</span>)}';
$r = '$1$2\$$3';
echo preg_replace($p, $r, $str);
```

This regex example appends `$` to the end of each span node in the subject HTML text.

Comment: Regex worked as given and its solve my problem. Domdocument shows error DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/fbcrawl/testing.php on line 20. Give a best link to learn abt reg expressions

Comment: I used [this source](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html) when first learning to use regular expressions. As for the Dom error, that is strange because saveHTML() takes an optional node parameter and I tested the code before posting the answer ...